# the page content is incomplete after visit a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I am new to Capybara. I try to use "visit root_path" and then check if the spicified tag is rendered correctly. Firstly there is "ElementNotFound" error. And i use "puts page.html" to see the response page content. And i found that only the static parts of the page are rendered. And all the other parts dynamically created by rails(<%= %>) are NOT. BTW, i put this test in requests folder. All Capybara config are default.

Did anyone come with similar problem like it?

Comment: I would try calling `sleep` for a couple seconds between when you load the page and when you execute your test, to make sure it's the html not getting loaded. It sounds like it's something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use lanchy gem and save_and_open_page in your tests. Check [this post](http://techiferous.com/2010/04/using-capybara-in-rails-3/)

Comment: Thank you all. It is fixed. The reason is that the test db is empty. see:http:[detail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296682/capybara-rspec-combination-cant-work-together-hanging-on-it-for-2-days)