# Capybara & rspec combination can't work together, hanging on it for 2 days

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I am new to capybara & rspec and i wrote a simple test(under spec/requests) to test the my root path:

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'spec_helper'

describe "select a course" do
  before { visit root_path }

  it "should render main page well" do
    puts page.html
    page.should have_xpath("//ul[@class='thumbnails']/li[1]")
  end
end
```

The root page contains both static and dynamic content which indeed contains the above xpath statement by firefinder verification. But the test failed. The reason was that after "visit root_path", the result(page.html) only contained the static part of the whole root. I don't know why.

I then try standalone capybara without rails & rspec and it worked correctly.
The spec_helper.rb:

```
    # This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'     
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'                                                    
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)                 
require 'rspec/rails'                                                          
require 'rspec/autorun'                                                        
require 'capybara/rspec'                                                       
require 'capybara/rails'                                                       

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,         
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.                                     
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}              

RSpec.configure do |config|                                                    
  # ## Mock Framework                                                          
  #                                                                            
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #                                                                            
  # config.mock_with :mocha                                                    
  # config.mock_with :flexmock                                                 
  # config.mock_with :rr                                                       

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures 
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"                        

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your  
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false   
  # instead of true.                                                           
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true                                     

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred          
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of     
  # rspec-rails.                                                               
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false                    
end
```

root page:

```
<div class="row">
  <%= render partial: 'shared/courses_category', object: @big_categories, as: 'courses_big_categories' %>
  <div class="span9 courses">
    <ul class="thumbnails"> 
      <% @courses.each do |course| %>
        <%= render(partial: 'shared/course', object: course) %>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And it should looked like:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
<li class="span3">
<div class="thumbnail">
  <a href="/courses/2"><img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="掌握ruby"></a>
  <div class="caption">
    <h5>掌握ruby</h5>
    <p class="course-summary">够fashin够cool的动态语言，应用广泛，简洁直观，让你一生受用</p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/select_courses/buy/2">购买</a>&nbsp;
    <a class="btn" href="/select_courses/store/2">收藏</a>
    <span class="course-price">¥200</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the result(not including the header and footer) was as follows:

```
<div class="row">                           
  <div class="span3 courses-category-panel">
    <h2>课程分类</h2>                       
  </div>                                    

  **<div class="span9 courses">               
    <ul class="thumbnails"></ul>            
  </div>**                                    
</div>
```

We could see that the following dynamic parts are NOT generated:

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/courses_category', object: @big_categories, as: 'courses_big_categories' %>

<% @courses.each do |course| %>
    <%= render(partial: 'shared/course', object: course) %>
<% end %>
```

Could anyone see this problem or help it?

Add some more info:
root_path is matched to Welcome#index which is defined as follows:

```
def index
    @big_categories = BigCategory.all
    @courses = Course.all
end
```

Comment: Are you creating the `@courses` in another before statement, or somehow getting the courses into the database?

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. It is because the test db is empty. I made a stupid mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this your entire testing file?

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'spec_helper'

describe "select a course" do
  before { visit root_path }

  it "should render main page well" do
    puts page.html
    page.should have_xpath("//ul[@class='thumbnails']/li[1]")
  end
end
```

It seems like your *subject* is not defined in the rspec file.

You should have `subject { page }` probably after `require 'spec_helper'`.